# How can I extract the maximum values along the horizontal and vertical from the coordinates of the grid using python?

Tags: python, numpy, integer, numbers

I was calculating the points of intersections from a grid. I want to use these points for further analysis like annotating the positions of the points of intersections on an image.

```
[(65, 1),(132, 1),(198, 1),(265, 1),(332, 1),(399, 1),(466, 1),(533, 1),(600, 1),(666, 1),(732, 1),(799, 1),(865, 1),(931, 1),(997, 1),(1063, 1),(1130, 1),(1196, 1),(65, 67),(132, 67)]
```

How can I obtain the maximum for the x-axis and y-axis in that list of coordinates?

The expected results are as follows

```
max_x = 1196
max_y = 67
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr= np.array([(65, 1),(132, 1),(198, 1),(265, 1),(332, 1),(399, 1),(466, 1),(533, 1),(600, 1),(666, 1),(732, 1),(799, 1),(865, 1),(931, 1),(997, 1),(1063, 1),(1130, 1),(1196, 1),(65, 67),(132, 67)])

max_x, max_y = arr.max(axis=0)
```

output:

```
[1196   67]
```

Comment: @Avandale, yes, Numpy tag was already there in the post

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested only in absolute max values, then probably easiest way is to unzip your points list to lists of y-s and x-s:

```
points = [(65, 1),(132, 1),(198, 1),(265, 1),(332, 1),(399, 1),(466, 1),(533, 1),(600, 1),(666, 1),(732, 1),(799, 1),(865, 1),(931, 1),(997, 1),(1063, 1),(1130, 1),(1196, 1),(65, 67),(132, 67)]
x, y = zip(*points)
max_x = max(x)
max_y = max(y)
```

But you could also just iterate through your points lists adding each x to x list you declared above, and y to y-list, if you haven't known zip function.